# Event notification on mobile and desktop from a website

Tags: push-notification

I'm wondering if using the server-sent events described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events , therefore from a web browser on desktop or mobile, once the user "subscribe" to it, gets the notification even if the browser is closed.

I imagine that the popup window that sometimes I get browsing on some sites, like the one below

[image]

is given by adding the server-sent events, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two parts in your question:

### Is the "Show notifications" popup related to server-sent events?

No.

This comes from the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API).

That popup is displayed when the JavaScript application running in the browser calls [`Notification.requestPermission()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission).

### Will server-sent events be received by the browser when it's closed?

No.

That's not the purpose of server-sent events. SSE is a mechanism for streaming data from a server to the browser, similar to WebSockets.

### How to send notifications to the user even if the browser is closed?

I'd refer you to other questions that have already been answered here:

- [Is there a way to display desktop notifications even when Chrome or Firefox is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311664/is-there-a-way-to-display-desktop-notifications-even-when-chrome-or-firefox-is-c)
- [Does service worker runs on background even if browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201067/does-service-worker-runs-on-background-even-if-browser-is-closed)
- [Send desktop notifications in Chrome or Firefox from a closed web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app?rq=1)